# malfunction in my flutter app while dealing with dialogues

Tags: flutter, dialog, widget

I use these dialogues for confirmation actions in which they return a true if the user confirmed to proceed with an action or false if they canceled.

For example, a logout action goes like so

```
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: ()async{
                      final bool result=await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                       
                        builder: (dialogueContext) => ActionDialogue(text: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',button: 'Logout'),
                      );
                      if(result==true){
                        await _auth.signOut();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700],fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
```

This is what it appears on the Ui

[image: This is what appears on the Ui]

The issue is that sometimes it decides to go rogue and return a dialogue with no text on its attributes like so.

[image: Without text]

This happens either on the buttons or the confirmation text. What could be the issue or what am i doing wrong.

Comment: any error on the console?

Comment: No error on console